# How do I invert a multidimensional-array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I have the following code:

```js
const BOARD = { X: 3, Y: 5 };

const board = new Array(BOARD.X)
    .fill(0)
    .map((_, idx) =>
        new Array(BOARD.Y).fill().map((elm, idx2) => (elm = `${idx},${idx2}`))
    );

console.log(board)
```

And is printing in the console:

```
[
  [ '0,0', '0,1', '0,2', '0,3', '0,4' ],
  [ '1,0', '1,1', '1,2', '1,3', '1,4' ],
  [ '2,0', '2,1', '2,2', '2,3', '2,4' ]
]
```

How can I invert the order of 'X' row, so it prints:

```
[
  [ '2,0', '2,1', '2,2', '2,3', '2,4' ],
  [ '1,0', '1,1', '1,2', '1,3', '1,4' ]
  [ '0,0', '0,1', '0,2', '0,3', '0,4' ]
]
```

Answer (score 2):

SIMPLY with [`reverse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method

```
board.reverse()
```

```js
const BOARD = { X: 3, Y: 5 };

const board = new Array(BOARD.X)
    .fill(0)
    .map((_, idx) =>
        new Array(BOARD.Y).fill().map((elm, idx2) => (elm = `${idx},${idx2}`))
    );
board.reverse();
console.log(board)
```

Answer (score 0):

Or generate it with `BOARD.X - idx - 1` for the x index.

```js
const BOARD = {
  X: 3,
  Y: 5
};

const board = new Array(BOARD.X)
  .fill(0)
  .map((_, idx) =>
    new Array(BOARD.Y).fill().map((elm, idx2) => (elm = `${BOARD.X-idx-1},${idx2}`))
  );

console.log(board)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
  top: 0;
}
```